# Properly return data from stream.on()

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, data-stream

I basically just want to return the object once the upload is finished, but the message that is send is `undefined`. How can I change the code to return the data.

`index.ts`: route to the upload API

```
app.post('/gcs/upload/:folder?', multer.single('file'), async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const folder: string = req.params.folder || '';
  const fileName: string = req?.file?.originalname || 'FileWithoutFileName.txt';
  if (!req.file) res.status(401).send('Missing File');

  res.status(200).send(await uploadFile(req.file, fileName, folder));
});
```

separate file to handle the upload functionality to `Google Cloud Storage`:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const UPLOAD_BUCKET: string = process.env.GCS_BASE_BUCKET || '';

async function uploadFile(file: any, fileName: string, targetFolder: string) {
  const destinationFilepath: string = `${targetFolder ? targetFolder + '/' : ''}${fileName}`;
  const storage = new Storage();
  const options = {
    destination: destinationFilepath,
    metadata: {
      contentType: file.mimetype,
    },
  };
  const bucket = storage.bucket(UPLOAD_BUCKET);
  const blob = bucket.file(destinationFilepath);
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream(options);

  blobStream.on('error', (err: Error) => console.log('error', err));

  blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
    return await blob
      .makePublic()
      .then(() => {
        return { message: `Success!\n File uploaded to ${blob.publicUrl}`, publicUrl: blob.publicUrl, bucket: bucket.name, fileName: blob.name };
      })
      .catch((e) => e);
  });

  blobStream.end(file.buffer);
}

export { uploadFile };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added a `Promise` and that solved the problem:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const UPLOAD_BUCKET: string = process.env.GCS_BASE_BUCKET || '';

async function uploadFile(file: any, fileName: string, targetFolder: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const destinationFilepath: string = `${targetFolder ? targetFolder + '/' : ''}${fileName}`;
    const storage = new Storage();
    const options = {
      destination: destinationFilepath,
      metadata: {
        contentType: file.mimetype,
      },
    };
    const bucket = storage.bucket(UPLOAD_BUCKET);
    const blob = bucket.file(destinationFilepath);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream(options);

    blobStream.on('error', (err: Error) => reject(err));

    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
      resolve({ message: `Success! File uploaded to ${blob.publicUrl()}`, publicUrl: blob.publicUrl(), bucket: bucket.name, fileName: blob.name });
    });

    blobStream.end(file.buffer);
  });
}

export { uploadFile };
```